# Sonatype Nexus a practical access control solution

Tags: nexus, access-control, sonatype

I am deploying the latest v2 Nexus Pro and find the access control model is overly complicated. I am looking for a simple solution (better can work with the new v3 too). We are a .net shop and here is the requirements:

1. I want to create at least two repos: a local NuGet repo (to store
   application's NuGet packages) and a Maven2 repo (to store all
   application final deployment units)
2. Only admins and build users able to upload to these repos.
3. Everyone can view everything, so developers can download all packages.

I have LDAP integrated, can anyone give me a step by step procedure to set this up,eg. for a build id.

Thanks
Jirong

Comment: Hi @Jirong-Hu welcome to SO ... What have you done so far ...? Please read for your future questions -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I've read all documents and tried everything it mentioned, just feel very messy. So I want to see if someone can help me to sort it out. Give me a very simple example for such a typical requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour does exactly what you want already. You just have to create the desired repositories and provide the respective LDAP roles with write access using external role mappings you create.

This is all covered in detail [in the documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/index.html).

Further to your detailed questions:

- if you don't have a group in LDAP you will have to assign the respective roles to the individual users in the repository manager, having a separate user/role for each build will probably be overkills
- repo targets are regular expressions to a path into a repository and really only work well with Maven repositories, for NuGet I would not use them unless you have strict naming conventions for the packages that will work
- you can use repository privileges to grant write access for individual repositories to your users

So steps would e.g. be

1. create repositories, the respective privileges for the repositories will be created automatically
2. create the roles and grant desired repository access to the roles
3. assign the roles to the users

Comment: I tried to read the document and different ways many times, and feel it's very messy. I have the following questions: 1. I don't have a LDAP group to represent the admins and build ids, they are individual ids. 2. Even I have such a group, which role in Nexus shall I map to? 3. Can you give me an example on exactly what need to be created, e.g. how to create the repo target, privilege, role, etc., for a nuget_local repo.

Comment: can you please tell me how to "assign the respective roles to the individual users in the repository manager"? We have AD integrated so the users are AD users, not internal Nexus users.

Comment: For LDAP usage you create an external role mapping that maps an LDAP role to a Nexus internal role. And that Nexus internal role has to have the privilege for upload to the respective repository and the UI role associated to the repo upload tab.

Comment: The problem is once I add the "Artifactory Upload" into the the new internal role (external map to LDAP group), users in that group can upload to all repos. Please see my role setting in the screenshot below.

Comment: Another issue is the Artifact Upload UI always displays successful message even the artifact is not uploaded and have this message in the log:"huj org.sonatype.nexus.rest.artifact.ArtifactContentPlexusResource - ResourceStoreContentResource, illegal request:Repository with ID='otpp-releases' does not allow updating artifacts."

Comment: The UI is always visible, but uploads will only work for repositories that the specific user has access to. This is done with repository privileges and potentially repository target privileges.

Comment: The error message you get says it all.. you are not allowed to upload artifact that are already deployed. So no overwriting. This can be configured per repository and defaults to not allowing redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done:

1. Create a local NuGet repo called NuGet_OTPP. I see a privilege
   called NuGet_OTPP (view) is created, not other CRUD privileges.
2. Create a New Repository Target Privilege, named NuGet_OTPP, with target "All (nuget)", Repository "NuGet OTPP". This create the four NuGet_OTPP (CRUD) privileges.
3. Create a role called "OTPP Deployer", add the above four NuGet_OTPP (CRUD) privileges, Nexus Anonymous Role, UI:Base UI Privileges, All Repositories - (read), All Repositories - (view), Artifact Upload.
4. Create a user called otpp_deployer in Nexus (this is already a domain user in LDAP), assign the above role.
5. Changed the password for the default user admin and deployment so nobody else can use them.

Do I miss anything? It's a brand new installation.

Comment: The above doesn't work well. Step4 created an internal Nexus user actually overwrites the LDAP user. Password has to be set inside Nexus instead of using LDAP. So I create a new role, e.g. called NuGet_OTPP_Deployer, maps to an LDAP group using External Role Mapping. But users in this role can upload artifacts all repos, not just only "NuGet_OTPP". Can anyone help me to fix this setup?

Answer (score 0):

@Manfred Moser, below is the screenshot for the role:
[image]